# Background images not found ( .pagespeed extension )

Tags: wordpress

I've got a problem regarding WordPress.
I tried to update my website to version 4.9.5.
After that I noticed that some of the background images (e.g. header and footer) are not shown anymore.

The link is now

`https://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/inc/header.jpg.pagespeed.ce.l_yeFhbkAn.jpg`

Does somebody know which plugin causes the .pagespeed extension? The file exists on my FTP server and is accessible via the original filename (.../header.jpg).
I tried to disable Autoptimize and WPSuperCache but no changes.
The downgrade to the last running WordPress version (via backup) shows the same behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide the list of all active plugins, which improving website speed/making cache.

Comment: Master Slider (Cache for slides), Sucuri Security - Auditing, Malware Scanner and Hardening, WP Super Cache (Cache), Yoast SEO, WP-Mail-SMTP, WP Tiles, Facebook Auto Publish, Easy SwipeBox

Comment: try to deactivate plugins one by one( before deactivate cache plugins: delete all caches ). this way you should find which one throws error. take attention to ` Easy SwipeBox`, `Master Slider (Cache for slides)`, `WP Super Cache (Cache)`

Comment: also, what was your Wordpress version before updating?

Comment: that would be the pagespeed module, which is active on webserver level. talk to your hoster maybe?